# What Codec to use for decode and encode the audio data for webrtc with ffmpeg?

Tags: webrtc

I want to use ffmpeg to decode the audio data received from webrtc and encode audio and send it to client side webrtc.

With ffmpeg, how can I find the right arguments for those ???

```
    AVCodecContext* m_encontext=NULL;
    AVCodecContext* m_decontext=NULL;

    AVCodec* encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(???);
    if (encoder != NULL)
    {
        AVCodecContext* context = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
        if (context != NULL) 
        {
            context->sample_fmt = ???;
            context->bit_rate = ???;
            context->sample_rate = ???;
            context->channels = ???;
            int res = avcodec_open2(context, encoder, NULL);
            if(res != 0)
                m_encontext = context;
        }
    }
    AVCodec* decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(???);
    if (decoder != NULL)
    {
        AVCodecContext* context = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder);
        if (context != NULL) 
        {
            context->sample_fmt = ???;
            context->bit_rate = ???;
            context->sample_rate = ???;
            context->channels = 1;

            int res = avcodec_open2(context, decoder, NULL);
            if(res == 0)
                m_decontext = context;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As audio codec, WebRTC supports PCMA, PCMU and Opus (preferred).

You can check [ffmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopus-1) to see the list of options to encode Opus codec.